# Gallery images returns 0 images for product page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, media-images, gallery, gallery-image

For one product I am getting gallery images 0.

in `gallery.phtml`

```
<?php $galleryImages = $block->getGalleryImages(); ?>
```

gives me count 0.
I checked it database table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` for row_id which gives me 7 value_id(which means 7 images) which is linked to `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`.

Whats the reason. How can i get all media gallery images.

`Gallery.php`

```
 public function getGalleryImages()
{
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

    \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->info("in images " .$images );


    if (!$images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
        return $images;
    }

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $galleryImagesConfig = $this->getGalleryImagesConfig()->getItems();
        foreach ($galleryImagesConfig as $imageConfig) {
            $image->setData(
                $imageConfig->getData('data_object_key'),
                $this->imageUrlBuilder->getUrl($image->getFile(), $imageConfig['image_id'])
            );
        }
    }

    return $images;
}
```

`getMediaGalleryImages` in file `Product.php`

```
 public function getMediaGalleryImages()
{
    $directory = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    if (!$this->hasData('media_gallery_images')) {
        $this->setData('media_gallery_images', $this->_collectionFactory->create());
    }
    if (!$this->getData('media_gallery_images')->count() && is_array($this->getMediaGallery('images'))) {
        $images = $this->getData('media_gallery_images');
        foreach ($this->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
            if (!empty($image['disabled'])
                || !empty($image['removed'])
                || empty($image['value_id'])
                || $images->getItemById($image['value_id']) != null
            ) {
                continue;
            }
            $image['url'] = $this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
            $image['id'] = $image['value_id'];
            $image['path'] = $directory->getAbsolutePath($this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']));
            $images->addItem(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($image));
        }
        $this->setData('media_gallery_images', $images);
    }

    return $this->getData('media_gallery_images');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `getMediaGalleryImages` giving wrong data.

*The MySQL query which you have run need additional **where** conditions for some fields.*

So, You have to add store_id = YOURSTOREID  and disabled = 0 and your condition.
**MYSQL  Query is:**

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` where store_id = YOUR_STORE_ID and disabled = 0
> ```

See the condition at `getMediaGalleryImages in file Product.php`

```
if (!empty($image['disabled'])
                || !empty($image['removed'])
                || empty($image['value_id'])
                || $images->getItemById($image['value_id']) != null
            ) {
```