# How to see inside $this object in Magento 2 logger

Tags: magento2, object, logging, psr-logger

How can I see inside the `$this` object in my logger file using prs logger?

I tried this

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->info("in getMediaGalleryImages " .json_encode($this));
```

But this gives me `{}` every time.

`[2019-05-29 10:07:24] report.INFO: in getMediaGalleryImages {} [] []`

What's the right method to see inside the $this object in Magento 2 logger.

Comment: try `$self` instead of `$this`

Comment: But $this is used in the code $this->hasData('media_gallery_images'), not self

Comment: Not sure but `$self` can do the trick.

Comment: why you need  `json_encode($this)`?

Comment: @AmitBera I am stuck in this issue so i am debugging it, you have any idea about this .  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276313/gallery-images-returns-0-images-for-product-page-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **DependencyInjection** instead of `ObjectManager`
2. 2nd argument of any Logger message is [**Context**](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/#13-context) - use it instead. Example:

```
$this->logger->warning('User cannot be logged in', ['username' => $user, 'ip' => $ip]);
```

3. Use `$this->getData()` instead of just `$this`